# Outlook for Mac - only sync calendar not emails

Tags: email, ms-office, calendar

Our company has migrated our Gmail accounts to Office 365. In my local Outlook for Mac client, I've deleted my old account and added the new one. But there is still a single calendar out of my control that didn't get migrated AFAIK that I would like to have on my Outlook Calendar. But if I re-add my old account, I get double of all my old emails.

Is there a way to tell Outlook for Mac to sync just the calendar from a certain account and not the emails for that account? I know you can do this in the native Apple Mail/Calendar clients thru the Internet Accounts settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no. When you add an account on Outlook it will add everything in the account that it has access to without a way of disabling one component.

Getting back to your question though, you could potentially add the Google calendar onto your Outlook web app (visit outlook.com and follow steps to add a shared calendar) - however that would only give you read access to the calendar.

So you have a lot of options of where to go from here:

1. You can export the Google calendar contents into an Outlook calendar and find a method of importing the events.
2. You can add the Google calendar as a read-only shared calendar inside the Outlook web app which will then sync to your Outlook desktop and Mobile clients.
3. You can add your Outlook Exchange account AND your Google calendars on the Apple Internet Accounts section and use the Built in Calendar app instead of the one inside Outlook.
4. You could go on your old Google Apps/G Suite account and move all your inbox items and sub folders into a Old Email folder of some sort, then at least it's out of your line of sight.

Keep in mind when IT decides to cancel the G Suite accounts your old calendar will be gone! So plan ahead.. it costs around $6/month per account, so it's only a matter of time before they decide the cost is not worth keeping it around.

Answer (score 0):

In *System Preferences → Internet Accounts*, select the account you want, then chose what you would like to have synchronized.

[image]

For example, in this account, I am only syncing Contacts.  So, add your out of date account and select to only sync the calendar that you're interested in.

Comment: Does Outlook for Mac use Internet Accounts? This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: This is how I have mine configured.  In my case, I just want contacts from a particular account.

Comment: I have the same configuration (using Exchange) and now syncing is working as expected

Comment: Using the desktop Outlook for Mac client?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook for Mac does not use the Mac's Internet Accounts users - it has its own accounts. And, it doesn't allow you to sync calendars only. In addition, it doesn't allow you to add a URL to a calendar as a shared calendar. The only workaround I've found is to:

1. Sign up for a new gmail for a dummy work account. Perhaps call it *your_personal_username*.**work**@gmail.com.
2. Go to [calendar.google.com](https://calendar.google.com) on your primary account (your_personal_username@gmail.com) and change your calendar settings to *Share with specific people or groups*, and allow your new work gmail to *Make changes to events*, or whatever setting you're comfortable with.
3. Add your new work gmail to Outlook for Mac. It will sync both email and the calendar, but you won't have to care about the email since it's empty.